# Odoo 10.0 invalid constraint

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

I've asked this question on [odoo.com here](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/10-0-error-while-validating-constraint-124586).

I'm trying to replace a field in the product.template view with a field of my own.

In the gui, click Sales/Sales/Products, select a product, click the Invoice tab - I want to change the "Add Task to Project" option to "Generate project from Template". That's the ultimate goal - but first I need to be able to at least add a field to the template view, and I'm failing at that!

Following the suggestions in the book https://www.amazon.co.uk/Odoo-Development-Essentials-Daniel-Reis-ebook/dp/B01KI1F302/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1507024599&sr=8-1&keywords=odoo+10+development+essentials , I've created the following xml in views/views.xml -

```
<odoo>

  <data>

    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_product_template_form_inherited">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

      <field name="name">MSUK view product template form</field>

      <field name="model">product.template</field>

      <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view" />

      <field name="arch" type="xml">

          <xpath name="//field[@name='project_id']" position="before">

            <field name="project_templates" />

          </xpath>     

      </field>

    </record>

  </data>

</odoo>
```

and in models.py:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api
from pprint import pprint
import logging 
class msuk_sales(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    project_templates = fields.Char('Templates', required=True) #String("template projects") #Many2one('project_project')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    # for record in project_templates:
        # logger.log(20, record)
```

My module is available when I click "Apps", so I'll not bother showing you the **manifest**.py

when I click "Upgrade", I get the following stacktrace:

```
2017-10-03 10:24:26,654 18191 INFO miningsearchesuk odoo.modules.loading: loading msuk_sales/views/views.xml                                                                        
2017-10-03 10:24:26,710 18191 ERROR miningsearchesuk odoo.modules.registry: Failed to load registry

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
        return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 677, in dispatch
        result = self._call_function(**self.params)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 333, in _call_function
        return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper
        return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 326, in checked_call
        result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 935, in __call__
        return self.method(*args, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 506, in response_wrap
        response = f(*args, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 889, in call_button
        action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 877, in _call_kw
        return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
        return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
        result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/module/module.py", line 527, in button_immediate_upgrade
        return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/module/module.py", line 484, in _button_immediate_function
        modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 82, in new
        odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 335, in load_modules
        force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 237, in load_marked_modules
        loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 156, in load_module_graph
        _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 95, in _load_data
        tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 845, in convert_file
        convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 915, in convert_xml_import
        obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 796, in parse
        self.parse(rec, mode)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 799, in parse
        self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 707, in _tag_record
        id = self.env(context=rec_context)['ir.model.data']._update(rec_model, self.module, res, rec_id or False, not self.isnoupdate(data_node), noupdate=self.isnoupdate(data_node), mode=self.mode)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1228, in _update
        record = record.create(values)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 363, in create
        return super(View, self).create(self._compute_defaults(values))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3839, in create
        self._fields[key].determine_inverse(record)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 1000, in determine_inverse
        getattr(records, self.inverse)()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 220, in _inverse_arch
        view.write(data)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 381, in write
        return super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3564, in write
        self._write(old_vals)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3716, in _write
        self._validate_fields(vals)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 1083, in _validate_fields
        raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating constraint"), tools.ustr(e)))
    ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

    Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType'
    None" while parsing /home/dominic.pain/miningsearchesuk/src/python/msuk_sales/views/views.xml:3, near
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_product_template_form_inherited">
          <field name="name">MSUK view product template form</field>
          <field name="model">product.template</field>
          <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
          <field name="arch" type="xml">
              <xpath name="//field[@name='project_id']" position="before">
                <field name="project_templates"/>
              </xpath>
          </field>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you write wrong xpath
it should be

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='project_id']" position="before">
     <field name="project_templates"/>
</xpath>
```

Comment: gah! Thank you! But... that now presents me with a different error:

ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

Element '<xpath expr="//field[@name="project_id"]">' cannot be located in parent view

Error context:
View `MSUK view product template form`
[view_id: 4370, xml_id: n/a, model: product.template, parent_id: 426]
None" while parsing.template</field>

<snip>

Comment: That means project_id field is not in parent view i. e. product.product_template_only_form_view. please check project_id exist in that view.

Comment: I can see it when I click "Fields View Get"...

<field name="project_id" attrs="{'invisible':['|', ('type','!=','service'), ('track_service', '&lt;&gt;', 'task')]}" can_create="true" can_write="true" modifiers="{'invisible': ['|', ['type', '!=', 'service'], ['track_service', '&lt;&gt;', 'task']]}"/>

Comment: yes but which view put project_id is different. check file product_template_views.xml there is no project_id field. so you must have to inherit view which really put project_id field.

Comment: ok, I'll try to find that. 

Thank you ever so much for you help, sir. It's really appreciated and has helped me immensely!