# How can I find which view a field is in, in Odoo 10.0?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xpath, odoo-10

My url is my.ip.address/web?debug=#id=5&view_type=form&model=product.template&action=179&menu_id=97

and I've clicked on the "INVOICING" tab. I want to replace "Project" with... well, anything, really! Just to prove I can do it before I try to do something more complex.

Building from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542095/odoo-10-0-invalid-constraint/46542804?noredirect=1#comment80040178_46542804), I'm now trying to find which view should be in my "inherit_id" field.

When I hover on "Project", I see the following:

```
Field: project_id
Object: project.template
Type: many2one
Modifiers: (really difficult to copy/paste, as the popup disappears onblur)
Relation: project.project
```

In my previous question, the person who answered pointed out that the view I was inheriting from did not include a field called "project_id". But... when I hit Technical, Fields View Get, project_id is displayed in the XML.

So I did a `grep -rn --include *.xml "Invoicing Policy"` * in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo, and found `addons/sale/views/sale_views.xml:627:                    <separator string="Invoicing Policy"/>`

I had a look at that, and found my way back up to the record id: `product_template_form_view_invoice_policy`

so now my view XML looks like this:

```
<odoo>
  <data>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_product_template_form_inherited">
      <field name="name">MSUK view product template form</field>
      <field name="model">product.template</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view.product_template_form_view_invoice_policy" />
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <xpath expr='//field[@name="project_id"]' position="before">
            <field name="project_templates" />
          </xpath>
      </field>
    </record>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

I've also tried

```
<field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view_invoice_policy" />
```

but whenever I upgrade my module through the gui, I get:

```
2017-10-03 13:19:11,524 21646 ERROR miningsearchesuk werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 180, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 168, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 249, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 184, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 170, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1308, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1282, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 591, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1463, in dispatch
    odoo.registry(db).check_signaling()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/__init__.py", line 52, in registry
    return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 59, in __new__
    return cls.new(db_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 82, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 335, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 237, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 156, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 95, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 845, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 915, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 796, in parse
    self.parse(rec, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 799, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 695, in _tag_record
    f_val = self.id_get(f_ref)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 782, in id_get
    res = self.model_id_get(id_str, raise_if_not_found)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 788, in model_id_get
    return self.env['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(id_str, raise_if_not_found=raise_if_not_found)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1075, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
    return self.xmlid_lookup(xmlid)[1:3]
  File "<decorator-gen-5>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 87, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1064, in xmlid_lookup
    raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: product.product_template_form_view_invoice_policy" while parsing /home/dominic.pain/miningsearchesuk/src/python/msuk_sales/views/views.xml:3, near
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_product_template_form_inherited">
      <field name="name">MSUK view product template form</field>
      <field name="model">product.template</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view_invoice_policy"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <xpath expr="//field[@name=&quot;project_id&quot;]" position="before">
            <field name="project_templates"/>
          </xpath>
      </field>
    </record>
```

In addition to the question "what should that id be?", I'd really like to know "and how would I have found that out for myself?" - please!

Answer (score 0):

Again you i think

First Go to settings and enable developer mode
Go to Settings=>User interfaces => Views
Search for model product.template

set filter Form and go through one by one you will get it. Use browser search (Ctrl + F) to find project_id

```
<record id="view_product_timesheet_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.template.timesheet.form</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale_timesheet.view_product_timesheet_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='project_id']" position="before">
                <field name="project_templates"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: sale_timesheet.view_product_timesheet_form has 
`<field name="track_service" position="after">
    <field name="project_id" attrs="{'invisible':['|', ('type','!=','service'), ('track_service', '&lt;&gt;', 'task')]}"/>
</field>`

restarted odoo, upgraded the module:




`ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

Field project_id does not exist

Error context:
View `MSUK view product template form`
[view_id: 4493, xml_id: n/a, model: product.template, parent_id: 723]`

Comment: Answer edited. also put dependency of sale_timesheet in your module.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error:`External ID not found in the system: product.product_template_form_view_invoice_policy`

1. Add dependency of `project` module to your module.
   `your_module/**manifest**.py -> depends :['product']
2. Make sure the external id 'product_template_form_view_invoice_policy` exist.

Hope the answer will help you.

Comment: I've already got:

`'depends': ['base', 'project', 'product', 'project_template', 'sale'],`

Comment: Did you restart your odoo server?

Comment: yes, I always restart it after every code change. Restart server, upgrade module